# Can't login to django admin despite correct superuser credentials

Tags: django, openedx

I am configuring openedx ecommerce which uses django admin.

I have successfully created a superuser credential as shown below:

[image]

However when I try to login to the admin panel the page submits and I am presented with the same login page with cleared fields - as shown below:
[image]

The log files do not update when attempting to login but there are some error messages that I can't seem to work out:

```
Dec 26 15:10:09 ip-172-31-21-194 [service_variant=ecommerce][django.request] WARNING [ip-172-31-21-194  2638] [/edx/app/ecommerce/venvs/ecommerce/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py:152] - Not Found: /
Dec 26 15:10:09 ip-172-31-21-194 [service_variant=ecommerce][django.request] WARNING [ip-172-31-21-194  2638] [/edx/app/ecommerce/venvs/ecommerce/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py:152] - Not Found: /
Dec 26 15:10:09 ip-172-31-21-194 [service_variant=ecommerce][django.request] WARNING [ip-172-31-21-194  2638] [/edx/app/ecommerce/venvs/ecommerce/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py:152] - Not Found: /
Dec 26 17:29:35 ip-172-31-21-194 [service_variant=ecommerce][django.security.csrf] WARNING [ip-172-31-21-194  2635] [/edx/app/ecommerce/venvs/ecommerce/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/middleware/csrf.py:160] - Forbidden (CSRF token missing or incorrect.): /admin/login/
Dec 26 17:29:35 ip-172-31-21-194 [service_variant=ecommerce][django.security.csrf] WARNING [ip-172-31-21-194  2635] [/edx/app/ecommerce/venvs/ecommerce/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/middleware/csrf.py:160] - Forbidden (CSRF token missing or incorrect.): /admin/login/
Dec 26 18:24:26 ip-172-31-21-194 [service_variant=ecommerce][django.request] WARNING [ip-172-31-21-194  2635] [/edx/app/ecommerce/venvs/ecommerce/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py:152] - Not Found: /
Dec 26 18:24:26 ip-172-31-21-194 [service_variant=ecommerce][django.request] WARNING [ip-172-31-21-194  2635] [/edx/app/ecommerce/venvs/ecommerce/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py:152] - Not Found: /
Dec 26 18:24:26 ip-172-31-21-194 [service_variant=ecommerce][django.request] WARNING [ip-172-31-21-194  2635] [/edx/app/ecommerce/venvs/ecommerce/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py:152] - Not Found: /
```

Comment: As the error indicates, you did not include the CSRF token in the form. Can you show the template?

Answer (score 2):

For the open edX ecommerce it is easier if you try this:

1. Go to the regular login, not /admin/login, but simply /login.
2. This will redirect to the lms login. Use your superuser credentials there.
3. On return, you will land in the django-oscar dashboard at the ecommerce.
4. Now you can navigate to /admin since you are already authenticated as superadmin.